# Jenkins pipeline stage for k8 rolling update strategy

Tags: kubernetes

I'm having jenkins stage to deploy kubernetes manifest file with rolling RollingUpdate method and i configured maxSurgeand and maxUnavailable value with 4 replicas copy of pod. while running jenkins my kubernetes yaml file is applying but after the deployment new changes been not reflecting.

In this case i need to login to worker node where my pod is running, then i need stop the deployment then i need to use docker rmi command to remove the container, finally i need pull the latest image to reflect the new changes.

jenkins file

```
stage('Deploy') {
        container('kubectl') {
            withCredentials([kubeconfigFile(credentialsId: 'KUBERNETES_CLUSTER_CONFIG', variable: 'KUBECONFIG')]) {
                def kubectl
                echo 'deploy to deployment!!'
                if(gitBranch == "devops") {
                    kubectl = "kubectl --kubeconfig=${KUBECONFIG} --context=arn:aws:eks:eu-central-1:123456789101:cluster/my-modulus-cluster"
                    echo 'deploy to my-modulus-cluster!'
                    sh "kubectl apply -f ./infrastructure/dev/my.yaml -n default --record"
                    sh "kubectl rollout history deployment myapp"
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here the k8 manifest file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 1
  minReadySeconds: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      backend
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myimage:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
            - containerPort: 3030
        readinessProbe:
          initialDelaySeconds: 1
          periodSeconds: 2
          timeoutSeconds: 1
          successThreshold: 1
          failureThreshold: 1
          httpGet:
            host:
            scheme: HTTPS
            path: /
            httpHeaders:
            - name: Host
              value: myhost
            port: 3030
```

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor?

Comment: I'm using AWS EKS cluster with version 1.20

Comment: What do you mean: " after the deployment new changes been not reflecting."? What exactly is happened?

Comment: After the deployment, new application code changes is not reflecting

Comment: Please list your pods. How long have they been active? Was there anything new after the update?

Comment: Good question, during the jenkins deployment my existing running POD not terminating its running with old time stamp only.

Comment: This would mean that jenkins is not deploying at all, or something went wrong. Can you check if Jenkins is working properly? Do you have any logs?

Comment: Hi this issue has been fixed now

Answer (score 1):

Inside the deploy stage i have added if condition to set image

```
sh 'echo "Starting ams Deployment"'
                    sh '''
                        if kubectl get deployments | grep ams
                        then
                            kubectl set image deployment ams ams=myimage:latest
                            kubectl rollout restart deployment ams
                        else
                            kubectl apply -f my.yaml -n default
                        fi
                    '''
```